# How to find maximum number of segments of a infinite rod with given N cuts

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Suppose we are given a rod of infinite length and we are also given N  segments like [L1 , L2).
This means we can cut rod at L1 and just before L2 to get one segment.Some segments may overlap.

For example we are given  N=4 and

```
[2,3)
[1,9)
[4,5)
[5,8)

We can chose

[2,3)
[4,5)
[5,8)
```

segments to get the maximum three segments. I dont know is there any well known good algorithm for it  ?If any please suggest me.I am able to do it manually but not able to get a good working algorithm.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're given a list of possible segments, some of which may overlap others, and you want the subset of the list that produces the maximum number of non-overlapping segments?

Answer (score 1):

Sort by the end points.

Iterate through the segments, picking whichever segments doesn't cause overlap with the previous segments (this can be checked by simply keeping track of the last end point and checking that the starting point is after that point).

This will always give the optimal solution.

For your example, after sorting, we have:

```
[2,3)
[4,5)
[5,8)
[1,9)
```

Then we go through `[2,3)`, `[4,5)`, `[5,8)` and `[1,9)`, picking all of them except `[1,9)`.

**Why this is optimal**

Obviously the segment with the smallest end point is going to be one of our choices, as any segment overlapping with it will have a bigger end point, thus could overlap with more segments starting at a bigger value, and any segment B overlapping with the segment A with the smallest end point will also overlap with any segment overlapping with A, thus B can't be a better choice than A.

From here, we repeat this argument for the next segment with the smallest end point that doesn't overlap with the previous end point, until we get to the end.

Comment: I was about to write the same answer. This is a more-or-less well known greedy problem (I knew it as "schedule the maximum number of shows without overlapping").

Answer (score 0):

This is actually one of the most common examples of dynamic programming vs greedy programming.
I actually can give you nothing more than this link: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-13-cutting-a-rod/
It will show you the dynamic way to do it.
Dukeling answer is a greedy algorithm.

What is a difference between dynamic and greedy?
Let me show you that on money.
Let's say you have $123 and have $1, $2, $5, $10, $20, $50 bills. How to do it with minimal amount of bills?

**Greedy** always picks up the best option at the moment. It will get the greatest bill that it can take at given moment. So first it will take 50, then 50, then 20, then 2, then 1.

But what if we had bills like $100, $1, $99, $24?
Greedy would take 100 first and then would take $1 23 times.

What **dynamic** does is analyzing the current decision basing on the ones made before AND correcting improper past decisions. This way you will always get the minimum amount of coins. (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/)

So:
Dynamic:

- slower
- always accurate
- more difficult

Greedy:

- straight-forward
- not always accurate (guess why are there only $1, $2, $5 and these multiplied by 10 :D)
- fast

Comment: My solution is greedy, but it's also optimal (though I stand to be corrected).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same task as the *Find a maximal set of non-overlapping segments.* on Codility.

I would like to provide the explanation for the greedy algorithm to solve this task and also the implementation in C++.

1. If the inputs are empty, return zero as there is no segment available.
2. If the inputs are not empty, there is at least one non-overlapping segment, the first one. Set the end of this from the B inputs as the current end.
3. The current end is used to to compare the A values against. The A value of the next acceptable A-B needs to be greater than the current end to be able to add it to the non-overlapping segments.
4. When it is so, increment the counter and set the end of the current A-B pair as the current end for subsequent comparison.
5. Iterate until we reach the end of the pairs.

The runtime complexity of this solution is `O(N)` because we go through the
pairs in the loop.

The space complexity of this solution is `O(1)` because we only allocate
constant memory for solving the task, independently from the number of inputs.

```
int solution(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B)                                    
{                                                                               
  if (A.empty()) return 0;                                                      
  const int N = A.size();                                                       
  int max_nonoverlapping_segments = 1;                                          
  for (int i = 1, end = B.front(); i < N; ++i) {                                
    if (A[i] > end) { ++max_nonoverlapping_segments; end = B[i]; }              
  }                                                                             
  return max_nonoverlapping_segments;                                           
}
```